# How to read all function a model with KO

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

I'm not sure if I am explaining this correctly, but I need to read all functions of a model with KO.

In this section of my code, I create a model called `Person`:

```
 //Create my model
 var Modelo_Person = function () {
 var _Person_ID = ko.observable(''),
    _Nombre_Person = ko.observable('')
        .extend({ required: true })
        .extend({ caracterPermitido: 'ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúñÑ_/-()&.' })
        .extend({ maxLength: 100 });
 return {
    Person_ID: _Person_ID,
    Nombre_Person: _Nombre_Person
 }
}
```

Here is View/Html:

```
 <- html ->
 <input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput:Modelo_Person.Nombre_Neumatico" />
<input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput:Modelo_Person.Nombre_Person" />
```

I have a file .js with ViewModel:

```
 //ViewModel.js
 $(function () {
 Obj_Person_ViewModel = new Person_ViewModel();
}

//Open modal where view inputs
self.Abrir_Modal_Interfaz = function () {
    var modal_interfaz = $('#Modal_Interfaz')
    self.clear_inputs();
    modal_interfaz.modal();

}

//here is my problem
self.clear_inputs = function () {
 //i want to read all controls o elemt like to...
 foreach(self.Modelo_Person in elemt)
 {
    //now to clean it  or see its proerties
    element('');
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your model to clean values.

```
   //Create model with validations
   var newUser = ko.validatedObservable({
       Name: ko.observable().extend({ requiered: true }),
       LastName: ko.observable().extend({ requiered: true })
   });

   //Set values
   newUser().Name("Test1");
   newUser().LastName("Test2");

   Object.keys(newUser()).forEach(function (key) {
        newUser()[key]("");
   });

   console.log("after reset");
   console.log("Name:" + newUser().Name());
   console.log("LastName:" + newUser().LastName());
```

Also I think you could return full object in model javascript file.